# Rails 3 : Chaining Save method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails. So far I'm liking it, but there are a few gotchas (codes logic that work in PHP but I don't know how in Rails).

For example:

```
u = User.first
u.age +=1
u.save
```

That works, but if I chain it, it throws an error

```
u = User.first
u.age+=1.save
```

the error thrown is undefined method 'save' for 1:Fixnum

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the chaining you are looking for like this

`u.tap { u.age += 1 }.save`

although that's not necessarily the best way to update an attribute and subsequently save. To do that, I would use `update_attribute`

`u.update_attribute(:age, u.age+1)`

Answer (score 1):

`u.age += 1` returns an integer which doesn't have a `save` method.

Comment: yeah, I figured so too, so in short, Rails doesn't really support chaining?

Comment: Depends on what kind of chaining you need. This is not a valid case :(. Something like "string ".strip.length or User.where(:age => 20).last are valid.